# Question from IQ test involving patterns of white, yellow, red, and grey squares

Tags: pattern

This is an IQ question from Brainzilla IQ test.The order seems a bit convoluted. Can someone please give me a fair answer?

[image]

Comment: That's a terrible IQ test, as it tests not only reasoning, but also color vision :/ They could fix it by using symbols instead of/on top of colors.

Answer (score 30):

> Reading the grids in natural (left to right, top to bottom) order, we have the following patterns:
>
>  Grey: A diagonal line of squares starting in the top-right, and moving  down-left:
>   [image]
>
>  Yellow: A line of squares going anti-clockwise around the edge of the square , increasing in length by one each time:
>  [image]
>
>  But wherever grey and yellow overlap, you get a red square instead.
>  So the missing grid should be:
>  [image]
>  Which is option **C**

Comment: This is a great answer fljx!!

Comment: ah, learned a new one with the yellow here...